# Use of toupper Function

Tags: c, tree

Essentially, I have a Binary tree created. My Binary tree will contain strings which can all be of changing case i.e. Hello, hello, HELLO.

I need to implement a function so that, when the tree is traversed, i.e. being searched for a name, inputted via the user, whatever the user inputs case wise, it will always find the name. i.e. Search Hello, HELLO will still be found, and displayed, and vice versa.

My tree uses a recursive structure, so I cant think of an easy way to implement a toupper function, or some other method, in my code.

The issue is, I need to be able to find Thomas, even if thomas is entered for example.
But I dont know where I can implement such a function, since the objective is not to manipulate the input within the Tree.

Any advice is great :)

UPDATE:

```
else if ((comparison = strcmp(search, root->name)) == 0) {
    return root;
} else if ((comparison = strcmp(search, root->name)) < 0) {
     return SearchTree(root->left, search);
} else if ((comparison = strcmp(search, root->name)) > 0) 
     return SearchTree(root->right, search);    `
```

Those are my comparisons and recursive calls, Search being the string containing the user input, but adding toupper to any of those recursive calls will only return an error.

Thomas.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Which part are you having problem with -- traversing the tree or converting strings to upper case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you simply do a case-independent comparison (`stricmp`) when you are searching the tree.

Because `stricmp` is a little slower than `strcmp`, if the tree is very large then you should look into always storing keys in lower case and doing the same to the search value so that you can use `strcmp` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

At each point you need to do character comparisons (in order to decide if something matches), convert both the query and the character you are considering to either upper or lower case, using the functions in `ctype.h` (toupper or tolower).  The fact that it's recursive should not matter - you only need to make the case consistent for the individual characters you are comparing at that moment, not the whole string.

(EDIT: I misunderstood the original question, which has since been clarified and sufficiently answered)

Also, using binary trees to do string lookups is weird.

Comment: I recommend you put the comparison stuff in your question, with a title like "update:"

Comment: Remember that `toupper` and `tolower` take an `int` parameter and will not convert an entire string

Comment: @gian what sort of thing would you think binary trees were suited to?

Comment: Sure, you can do a binary search, but why not just build a proper trie?